# Stop reactive form submit if validation fails in angular

Tags: angular, crud, angular-reactive-forms

My last problem in this project is that once all the input fields are empty , partially filled or invalid and if the user clicks the submit button  by mistake the invalid data from the input field gets added to the main table.

The code that I tried is:

Typescript:

```
    onSubmit(){
this.submitted=true;
if(this.formName.invalid){
return;
}
if(this.submitted){
this.showModal=false
}
}
```

Please guide me about what I am missing.

Edit 1:As suggested, I have already inserted all the required validations and they are working perfectly fine for all the input fields. My issue is that the invalid input data also gets added by default to the output if the user SUBMITS the button by mistake.
Please  guide accordingly.

Comment: Can yu please form that code in stackBlitz?

Answer (score 4):

you have to validate your form before you submit. There are two ways to do this:

**In Component.ts**

```
onSubmit() {
   if(this.form.valid) {
     /* write your code here */
   }
}
```

**In Component.html**

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" [disabled]="!form.valid">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use validators while creating the form.

```
 this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            title: ['', Validators.required],
            firstName: ['', Validators.required],
            lastName: ['', Validators.required],
            email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
            password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]],
            confirmPassword: ['', Validators.required],
            acceptTerms: [false, Validators.requiredTrue]
        });
```

Here, registerForm will become valid only if it satisfies all the validations specified. Here all fields make as required by adding the required validator. And the minimum length for the password field is 6 also.

Then the form will be valid only if the validation become successful.

Then in submit function, you can check the form validity by using

```
submit(){
if(!this.registerForm.valid){
return false;
}
else {
//process you request
}
}
```

[CheckThisExample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-reactive-form-validation-aojelm)

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to validate the reactive form on submit.

**HTML**

```
 <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="myReactiveForm">
            <div formGroupName="userDetail">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="FirstName">First Name*</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtFName" formControlName="fname"
                        placeholder="First Name">
                    <small
                        *ngIf="!myReactiveForm.get('userDetail.fname').valid && myReactiveForm.get('userDetail.fname').touched"
                        class="text-danger">First name required.</small>
                </div>
</form>
```

**TypeScript**

```
    export class Form2Component implements OnInit {
          myReactiveForm: FormGroup;
  }
```

**Submit Method**

```
 onSubmit() {
   if (this.myReactiveForm.invalid)
     return false;
  else
    console.log(this.myReactiveForm);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input.
I checked and found that  I have already worked on the same line as suggested by you . But still  my problem persists, that the invalid input data gets added by default to the main output table .How to prevent invalid data to be accepted is the crux of the problem.